# Playing music in background from a service in android

Tags: android, service, background, media-player

I'm getting nervous... Could somebody tell me, why the hell the following code does not want to work?

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);
        player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        player.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        player.start();

//other stuff here, which run perfectly...
```

the audio file is there, i have the wakelock permission (without it does not work either...). No error message, the rest of the code is fine, but the ....... player is not playing anything.
Please help me before it snaps a blood vessel in my brain!

Edit: some more information:
the audio is .mp3 format, 77kb/s

Comment: @keybee.. did you observe any errors in `logcat`. Can you please paste your error logs also?

Comment: Of course, I will as soon as I get home, but there was no errors.

Comment: I cannot beleive it... The solution: it needs to be written like this: `MediaPlayer p = Mediaplayer.create(this, filename)` because p.create will call the static method, and it will return a new instance of a MediaPlayer, which is never stored. Then, I called start() on the default-constructed instance...

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't get you.. Is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes, I had this: `MediaPlayer player;` and this `player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.policesiren);` - but it needs to be written in a single line (`MediaPlayer p = Mediaplayer.create(this, filename)`). But thanks for trying helping me, unfortunately my questions don't have much interest. Maybe I am asking wrong...

Comment: @keybee.. actually you can still do it by declaring as `private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;`. You can refer to this question for a sample implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413038/error-while-trying-to-retreive-metadata-from-a-remote-mp3-file-android/15435415#15435415 and atleast on android `MediaPlayer`, `Stagefright` or `android-camera`, I will definitely read the questions :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: it needs to be written like this: `MediaPlayer p = Mediaplayer.create(this, filename`) because `p.create` will call the static method, and it will return a new instance of a `MediaPlayer`, which is never stored. Then, I called `start()` on the default-constructed instance, that is why it was not working.